# How to add a resource file to Visual Studios so that it's visible in "Select Resource" dialog?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer, resx

In Visual Studio you can edit image of a button control using the GUI editor (aka "designer").

I want to organize my resources into two `*.resx` files placed in the "Properties" folder of the project. My problem is that the "Select Resource" dialog in Visual Studio is only displaying the "Properties\Resources.resx" file, and none of other `*.resx` files.

How can i add a file to the "Project resource file" drop down? If can't, why is it a drop down select than?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Select Resource Dialog Box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9928ad3f(v=vs.100).aspx) shows:

- Main project resource which is `Properties\Resources.resx`
- All `.resx` files which are located at root of project.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way to get access to resources which are not placed at root of the project?

Comment: The folder name is added to the namespace in the resx Designer file

Comment: @CADbloke Looking into the screenshot that I sared, OP is asking if he can select Resource2 which is in Folder1? → The resource designer still doesn't show it in the dropdown in VS 2017.