# Project with multiple resource files (.resx): Images do not show up in WinForms Designer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, windows-forms-designer, resource-files

I've got a project with some resource files which contain png-images. I want to use these images in the winforms designer to set the image-property of various ToolStripMenuItems.
The problem is, the designer does not show any resources except the ones in the standard resource file (Properties.Resources.resx).

I noticed that in the "Select Resource" dialog there is e dropdownlist to select the resource file, but it shows only the standard resource file and none of the other resource files i've added.

So how can I get the WinForms Designer to recognize my resource files?

I am aware that simply moving all my resources to the Properties.Resources.resx file would work, but that is not an answer to my question.

I am using Visual Studio 2017 Professional.

[image: Designer]

Comment: [How to add a resource file to Visual Studios so that it's visible in “Select Resource” dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37444859/3110834)

Comment: @RezaAghaei so its not possible? I don't want dozens of .resx files in the root directory of my project.

Comment: No easy way. You may want to dig into the internal implementations to do [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47615439/3110834). There's a `ResourcePickerDialog` which asks from `ResourcePickerService` about resource files. The default (internal) implementation returns what I mentioned in the linked post.

Comment: Also in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36096989/3110834), you can find how to register a `UITypeEditor` for a `Type` in visual studio.

Comment: @RezaAghaei I was hoping there was a more straight-forward way to do something simple like this, but I guess not. Thank you very much for the insight though, I'll look into it.